# Excel VBA Navigate Through Same Window or Tab

Tags: excel, vba, url, window

I'm new at excel VBA programming so for those it may be very easy question but i need to learn it.

I have code part like this :

```
Sub Calculate()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 1000
        Dim Test As Object
        Dim IE As Object
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        IE.Visible = False
        IE.navigate "https://www.somewebsite.com/" & Cells(i, 2).Value

        Do
        DoEvents

        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    'some code here
.
.
.
.

    Next i 
    End Sub
```

This code will work as get some data from the same website with different endings. Each has written on some range (for example (A1:A1001)).

My question is each of this window opened visibility as hidden and get some data from web page. It takes too much time

I want each link opened in one window or one window with different tab (I don't know which one takes longer time) Each of solution is okay but preferred one is same window navigate each link.

I would like your help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're after, but from the sound of it you need IE automation (among other things) pulling websites into tabs within the same window.

This may be helpful:

```
.IE.Navigate2 "www.somewebsite.com", CLng(2048)
```

Comment: Not that worked for me. I also create other object called test to open empty IE than try this to make tab for it but code stucked at ready state

Comment: so any different opinion ? I found some code from here but it also did not work for me for the same window

Comment: Solved i forgot to add html controls